# How to acces getSystemService in Application class

Tags: android

I want to access the TELEPHONY_SERVICE system service in the Application class, but my app crashes when I run it.

```
public class SimpleDhtApplication extends Application {


    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String portStr = tel.getLine1Number().substring(tel.getLine1Number().length() -4);
    final String myPort = String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(portStr) * 2));
}
```

I think I am not accessing the context correctly, can somebody help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the onCreate method of the Application class first. Within the onCreate, put the code  you have so it would look like:

```
public class SimpleDhtApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String portStr = tel.getLine1Number().substring(tel.getLine1Number().length() -4);
        final String myPort = String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(portStr) * 2));
    }
}
```

**Update**: Watch out for tel.getLine1Number(); it may return null as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you explain as to why this is necessary!

Comment: @Nikhil Sure. When the Application class is constructed, the base Context is initialized to null. Take a look at the Application class source. That's why you were getting a NullPointerException. After onCreate, the base context is initialized properly, so calling this.getSystemService works.