# Android: onCreate boolean not changing

Tags: java, android

In an android application that I am developing Im using a thread, and to make sure I dont get the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" I use a boolean called donecreate. Problem is that Android studio says I have a "java.lang.NullPointerException at picLoop.run(picLoop.java:24)"

Code main class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;

import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class main extends Activity {
public Boolean donecreate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new eyeCanvas(this));
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    docreate();
}
public void docreate(){
    donecreate = true;
}
public void checkHead(){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(am.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HEADPHONES",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }



}
```

Code: pic loop

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;



//**Threading
public class picLoop extends Thread {
private eyeCanvas eye;
private main main = new main();
public picLoop(eyeCanvas eye) {
    this.eye = eye;
}

@Override
public void run(){


    Canvas c = null;

while(true) {
if(main.donecreate){ //<-- where error is
main.checkHead();
}

try {
  //  head.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
    c = eye.getHolder().lockCanvas();
    synchronized (eye.getHolder()) {
        eye.onDraw(c);
    }
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        eye.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}

try {
    sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
   }

   }
```

Also if you guys could give me feedback on how I submitted, It would help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of things wrong with the assumptions you're making. Firstly, if your `Thread` requires your `Activity` to be created, *don't start it until your `Activity` is created*. Manage the lifecycle of this object within the `Activity` itself, i.e.:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Start your work here
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Stop your work here
}
```

Secondly, please don't use the static access approach being recommended -- that makes the assumption that there is only one `Activity` instance (which is wrong immediately on a configuration change, and/or if you start another instance of that `Activity` in the task). And even if that assumption *were* true, you would need to set it back to `false` in `onDestroy()` (still, don't do that).

Answer (score 2):

You can't create activities like you're trying to do. You can NEVER EVER do 'new Activity()', as the activity needs to be launched by the system to get set up properly and go through its lifecycle as intended.

So remove the line `private main main = new main();`.
To do what you're trying, make the boolean a static variable.

Change

```
public Boolean donecreate;
```

to

```
public static Boolean donecreate;
```

Then you can access it like you're trying to do, without creating an instance of main Activity.

Comment: definitely follow @Kasper's advice and don't create new instances of Activities.

Answer (score 0):

try setting donecreate to false initially

```
public class main extends Activity {
    public Boolean donecreate = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request system service on application context, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22699802/3379437).
So create a static variable in application class, initialize it like `instance = this;` in onCreate of Application class and then you'll be able to get app context whenever you want.